# How to avoid repetition of same row in ms sql?

Tags: sql-server

how can i avoid the insertion of same row in multiple time in ms sql ?

```
     SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("insert student_vs_testsession_details(student_id,testsession_id,testsession_status,test_type) values('" + id + "','" + Test + "','','" + s_testtype + "') where  NOT EXISTS(select student_id from student_vs_testsession_details where testsession_id='" + lb_testid.Text + "' and student_id='"+id+"')", con);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make `(student_id, testsession_id)` the primary key of the table, then it is impossible to insert two tuples with the same values for this pair of attributes.
Refer to the [SQL server reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms174979%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for details. I believe the syntax should be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE student_vs_testsession_details (
    student_id integer,
    testsession_id integer,
    ...,
    CONSTRAINT MY_PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT
           PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (student_id, testsession_id)
           WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
);
```

Or you can [add the primary key constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms190273%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) using an `ALTER TABLE` statement.

[Edit]

If you don't want to use primary key constraints, you can create a `UNIQUE` constraint ([see Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)), like this:

```
CREATE TABLE student_vs_testsession_details (
    student_id integer,
    testsession_id integer,
    something_else varchar(10),
    CONSTRAINT MY_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT
           UNIQUE (student_id, testsession_id)
);
```

or you add the constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE student_vs_testsession_details ADD CONSTRAINT MY_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT
    UNIQUE (student_id, testsession_id);
```

Comment: but i cant change it as a primary key in my table.. those values are repeating for some other purposes . what to do ?

Comment: Try replacing `PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED` with `UNIQUE` (and remove the `WITH` clause). The [SQL Server Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979(v=sql.105).aspx) implies that this is possible.